# Is there a way to track if an object has changed with ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

is there a way to track if an object has changed with ReactiveUI? Basically does/can the ReactiveObject base class store the original values for the fields so it can track change?

If a property has changed then i need to know.

If a property was changed but then put back to the original value I don't want to know.

Can this be achieved ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ReactiveObject](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/bdb3c792b8c9033751b887615add11acc42475e7/ReactiveUI/ReactiveObject.cs) has a PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged, so it's part of the base class. There's a Example of how [to use it](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/bdb3c792b8c9033751b887615add11acc42475e7/ReactiveUI.Tests/ReactiveNotifyPropertyChangedMixinTest.cs). The base class will not store the original value for the change, you would need to handle that event with a PropertyChangedEventHandler or Changing to store the original values.